# JoptionPane is blank sometimes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I use this style in my production code:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "message", "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} else {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "message", "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

It works well for most of the time, but sometimes it just shows a blank dialog with only a title. Any idea about this issue?

Comment: the snippet looks just okay - must be something else which will be hard to track down: try to make it reproducible somehow and debug, not much can be done to help you, sorry.

Comment: Add some **logging**, and then you can see when it is happening. One (unprobable) thing could be that the message causes a problem. For a String message even more unlikely. Maybe `parent`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is because of `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` and    `SwingUtilities.invokeLater();` .

But, are you sure your code is correct?

These are the implementations of `showMessageDialog()`

```
showMessageDialog(Component c, Object msg);

showMessageDialog(Component c, Object msg, String title, int messageType)

showMessageDialog(Component c, Object msg, String title, int messageType, Icon icon)
```

But in your code, your first argument takes an `String` !!

Comment: Why? It's said that all GUI related operations must run on the EDT.

Comment: run your whole program GUI inside one EDT. Assume your JFrame class name is 'GUI'. Then, SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable(){new GUI})); Seperate EDT for each GUI is not needed always unless otherwise the GUI is very heavy. In here, it is just a small message box!

Comment: However, you can check whether my answer is correct or wrong by checking it by your self.

Comment: The problem is that this code can be invoked from either EDT or other threads, so I must do the check.

Comment: @ZhaoYi: Change the title and message in the message box of SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(). Then only you can find which thread is giving the error. I am 100% sure one of these threads are causing the issue, most probably invokeLater(). Because I had the same issue once

Comment: @ZhaoYi: Please have a look at my edited answer! I think you should get an error! I didn't notice it at the first time!

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected them. How did you fix this issue last time?

Comment: @ZhaoYi: By removing the invokeLater(). How did you manage to solve? If my answer helped you, you can select it as the selected answer, so this thread got a solved question :)

Comment: If I remove the `invokeLater`, this code will violate the EDT rule, and may cause the GUI to freeze. Remember that this code may also be invoked outside the EDT. Of course I'll mark your answer as selected if you help me solve it. :)

Comment: @ZhaoYi: There is no need of putting each and every GUI element into a EDT. So, if your application got 10 Jpanels, 10 JDialogs and 20 JOptionPanes, will you create 40 threads? No, it is completely incorrect

Comment: You may misunderstand my point... I have some background threads that need to call this code, so I must force the code to run on EDT.

Comment: @ZhaoYi: ohh..In that case yes..Sorry :)

Comment: @kleopatra: Please do not lie. I came here after trying that in my own code. Or you are not sure about what you are talking. You can't pass a String where a 'Component' is expected. OP corrected it after I mentioned, as he has commented. What you now see is an edited code

Comment: you are right, overlooked you stating _first_ parameter. Calling that _lying_ is a bit ... strong, don't you think? And as you might have noticed: typically I'm very sure about what I'm talking about, at least as far as Swing is concerned. Anyway, the downvote is for your first sentence ...

Comment: @kleopatra: oh, I am sorry. As a policy, I don't do downvote. I normally get annoyed when people do downvote, specially without considering the real issue. I dnt care about your downvote, but I dnt like the feeling of guilty. So, Please accept my apology for the bad language I might have used, mostly occurred because of my age, which majority are loose tempered... :)